# How can I efficiently write down my personal problems for further auto-analysis?

Tags: structure, psychology-of-writing, brainstorming

When I have some personal problems in relationships or there are worrying issues about life in general and I am really upset about the situation, in order to “solve it”, or efficiently think about it, I tend to dump all data I have about this “mental” situation into some electronic text document, word, etc. There once I have all possible information, I tend to add hypotheses about why this happens, what should be done, etc, in a very similar way the scientific method is applied in order to solve problems. Sometimes this works for me and I finally find a “solution” to my problem, or at least I finally stop worrying about it. Afterwards I feel a bit impotent about this and I think that my brain or mind is not strong or skilled enough in order to do it by itself without needing it to dump all info into paper or other external system.

Therefore my question is, how can I efficiently write down my personal problems for further auto-analysis? Please answers based on facts, specific expertise or references.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm not sure your question is about the skill of writing, really. It is about solving personal problems, so perhaps it could fit better on [interpersonal.se]. If it isn't counted as too opinion-based. We are not a forum but a Q&A site, so questions we can answer are those that can potentially have one "correct" answer. I don't think that is the case for your question. Take a look at our [tour] and [help] pages, they should make things clearer regarding what we can and can't help you with. :)

Comment: Ok, I understand. So I rewrote the question. What do you think now?

Comment: I write lists, then I shift them around… I'm not sure about your "come down" or crash afterwards. That might just be a bit of post-wrestler fatigue, or the depressive end of a manic period. I don't think you are "doing it wrong". Use what works!

Comment: What is the audience for your writing? Just yourself? Is the content of the writing really that important or is it the process of writing it down to work through issues. Unfortunately I'm not sure that this is a writing question though I do sympathise with your efforts.

Comment: @wetcircuit could you please switch to answer and explain a little bit more which kind of lists and how ? I mean bullet lists or others , etc

Comment: @linksassin in principle just myself and  I have the feeling that the important thing here is the process per se but anual I try to summarise at the end my findings or conclusions so that I can quickly revisit them later . This process also helps me since afterwards I feel a bit lighter or less worried than at the beginning

Comment: @linksassin why did you put it on hold ?

Comment: I reframed the question again, can you please check ?

Comment: I voted to put it on hold because it is opinion based. The most optimal way to write down personal issues to help deal with them will vary by the person. You could make it less opinion based by specifying a particular goal, "How can I write down X to achieve Y?" and people can respond with ways they have done it. "Most optimal" isn't a clear definition and we can't determine what a good answer is.

Comment: I did edit it again. Can you please check? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Q: Do we write down problems that we address using the scientific method?

A: Yes. We dump all this information on static media all the time, both for our benefit and for the benefit of others. We do so not only because our brain is limited, but because sharing data, storing information and reproducibility of experiments are all key elements of progress.

---

Consider the general case of a scientific problem, in which you have spent time clarifying in your head what the observables are, what the assumptions are, what the model is and what experiments you need to perform to verify your model.

You can now retain all this information in your head, and it will only be useful to you as long as you can remember it. Alternatively you can write it down and share it with others, or with your future self.

A good writeup:

- automatically highlights the differences between the new and the previous models;
- implicitly indicates the experiment that would most discriminate between the two models;
- suggests what observables you should collect in such experiment;
- allows you to pass this information to others in a manner that that they could replicate your experiment and obtain your results.

In doing so you have helped all of us, and while we may never ascertain truth using such approach, we can still try to remove errors.

Comment: @Opentheway definitively worth writing down everything. By the way, many a great works in science and philosophy were born this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I wonder how could I do this more efficiently or if there are guidelines that might be suggested